# C++ Program crashes after using -> Operator

Tags: c++, crash

I am working on a project to design a game in C++ and my program keeps crashing when I try and get a move from the player. The program allows the user to chose for each of the two players if it will be a computer player or a human player. If it is a human player it collects the name for the player.

When the program starts, my main class creates a game object, runs the **selectPlayers()** function and then runs the **play()** function. The program is loading, asking me for human or computer for each player, collecting the name for humans and displaying the board (which gets displayed in the play() function, and then it crashes with a window that pops up with message

> program stopped working, windows is looking for a solution

Added a comment in the code below to show where the problem is. If I put a cout above that line it prints, but nothing after that line prints... And if I put a cout on the very first line of the makeMove method in my HumanPlayer class, it doesn't get printed, so the program is crashing before getting into the method.

Here is the header for my game class:

```
#include "Board.h"
#include "Player.h"
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GAME_H_INCLUDED
class Game
{
    Board b;
    int turn;
    bool winner;
    Player* player1;
    Player* player2;
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void selectPlayers();
    Player* nextPlayer() const;
    void play();
    void announceWinner();
};

#endif // GAME_H_INCLUDED
```

And the class itself:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "HumanPlayer.h"
#include "RandomPlayer.h"
#include <iostream>
Game::Game()
{
    b.reset();
    turn = 1;
    winner = false;
}
Game::~Game()
{

}
void Game::selectPlayers()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter type for Player 1 (Human/Computer): ";
    std::cin >> type;
    while(x == 0)
    {
        if(type.compare("Human") == 0)
        {
            x = 1;
            std::cout << "Enter name for Player 1: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            HumanPlayer p(name, LIGHT);
            HumanPlayer * player1 = &p;
        }
        else if(type.compare("Computer") == 0)
        {
            x = 1;
            RandomPlayer p(1, LIGHT);
            RandomPlayer * player1 = &p;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter Human or Computer for Player 1: ";
            std::cin >> type;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Enter type for Player 2 (Human/Computer): ";
    std::cin >> type;
    x = 0;
    while(x == 0)
    {
        if(type.compare("Human") == 0)
        {
            x = 1;
            std::cout << "Enter name for Player 2: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            HumanPlayer p(name, DARK);
            HumanPlayer * player2 = &p;
        }
        else if(type.compare("Computer") == 0)
        {
            x = 1;
            RandomPlayer p(2, DARK);
            RandomPlayer * player2 = &p;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter Human or Computer for Player 2: ";
            std::cin >> type;
        }
    }
}
Player* Game::nextPlayer() const
{

}
void Game::play()
{
    while(winner == false)
    {
        b.display();
        if(turn%2 == 1)
        {
            player1->makeMove(b); //PROGRAM CRASHES HERE
            ++turn;
        }
        else
        {
            player2->makeMove(b);
            ++turn;
        }
    }
}
void Game::announceWinner()
{

}
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change all the code like this:

```
        HumanPlayer p(name, LIGHT);
        HumanPlayer * player1 = &p;
```

to this:

```
        player1 = new HumanPlayer (name, LIGHT);
```

In your code you created a local variable that you assign something to it. The member variable in the class is never initialized.

Comment: Don't forget to delete these in the destructor! Or just use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The crash is happening because `player1` is a wild pointer (i.e. it doesn't contain a legitimate value). It looks like you're *trying* to assign a value to it, but doing it incorrectly, as follows:

```
HumanPlayer p(name, LIGHT);
HumanPlayer * player1 = &p;
```

There are two problems here. Firstly, the object you're declaring is a local variable, so trying to store a pointer to it is a big mistake. It goes out of scope and gets destroyed within a couple of lines. Secondly, you're declaring a totally separate `player` pointer here, rather than using the one that's a member of the class. The result is that you're storing a local variable in a local pointer, so your program has nothing to work with later.

Instead, those lines should be instantiating a new instance of the player class on the heap (or free store). Conventional C++ would use the 'new' operator like this:

```
player1 = new HumanPlayer(name, LIGHT);
```

However, if you're using a modern compiler, you really should be using smart pointers instead. That means your `Game` class should declare the pointers like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Player> player1;
```

And the code to assign to them should be done like this:

```
player1 = make_shared<HumanPlayer>(name, LIGHT);
```

Obviously you'll need to make similar changes for `player2` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `player1` or `player2` in `Game.selectPlayers()`. Instead you create a *new temporary* variable either of `Human` or `Random` `Player` type, which goes out of scope after method ends.

Answer (score 0):

You got uninitialized data in your class as you're not initializing the pointers. Either set them to `NULL` or used a pointer swapper (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`) to manage them as they'll take care of the initialization for you.

Unlike languages like C# or Java, C++ does not set your member variables to default values unless they've got a default constructor, and pointers don't!